# Query Postgis to convert UTM to Lat Long in decimal degrees

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

I want the Postgres / PostGIS queries to convert the UTM coordinates of the SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 20N (EPSG: 31974) projection to the Decimal Degrees projection. Separating longitude and latitude into distinct columns.

Comment: What did you try to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ST_Transform` to reproject the data, then `ST_X` and `ST_Y` to extract the latitude and longitude.

```sql
WITH src AS (select st_geomfromtext('POINT(0 5000000)',31974) geom31974)
SELECT 
    ST_transform(geom31974,4326) geom4326,
    ST_asText(ST_transform(geom31974,4326)) txtgeom4326,
    ST_X(ST_transform(geom31974,4326)) longitude,
    ST_Y(ST_transform(geom31974,4326)) latitude
FROM src;
```

Comment: I understood, why use reference 4326 and not another? Is this for any input reference?

Comment: Without changing the database, can you retrieve this information (lat lat in decimal degrees) in java? I'm trying but I can not. I am using the JTS from vividsolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a conversion of values in your queries, I believe the best solution to be to reproject your data, then to save those geom values as attributes.